# How to handle slow network connections with UIAutomation

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I noticed that all my UI tests fail when the network is slow. For instance a user would try to login and then the next screen wouldn't load fast enough in order for another UIElement to be on screen.

How can I handle a slow network connection without using a delay() ?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at multi-threading. When handling network connections, you **should** make all this processing in a secondary thread. If not, the main thread will be blocked and the app will become unresponsive to the user.

Multi-threading is a very big subject. I recommend you to start looking at [Apple's reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for this. You can also refer to [a great course on iTunes U](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016) (lecture 11).

If you just want to give it a shot, here's the actual code (similar) that you will need:

```
dispatch_queue_t newQueue = dispatch_queue_create("networkQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(newQueue, ^{

// here you need to call the networking processes

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     // if you need to update your UI, you need to get back to the main queue.
     // This block will be executed in your main queue.

    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I am fairly well versed with GCD and we do implement all network calls in background threads, however, the issue is that my automation code is seeking a UIElement on screen and it is not currently visible yet. 

To give you an example, say your about to load a screen full of text but you have a spinner going until the text loads. I want my automation code to be able to wait for the text to load but I don't want to use a target.delay()

Comment: What can be used instead of target.delay()? It seems to be blocking the app's main thread.

Comment: @maremmle I know it's been a while but I just posted a new answer explaining how we wait for networking / other background tasks in UIAutomation tests just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is using a delay. I usually have a activity indicator when loading stuff from the internet. So I add a delay while the activity indicator is displaying

```
while (activityIndicator.isVisible())
{
    UIALogger.logMessage("Loading");
    UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `pushTimeout` and `popTimeout` methods in the `UIATarget`. You can find the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/pushTimeout).

Here is one code example from our iOS app UIAutomation tests:

```js
// Tap "Post" button, which starts a network request
mainWindow.buttons()["post.button.post"].tap();
    
// Wait for maximum of 30 seconds to "OKAY" button to be valid
target.pushTimeout(30);

// Tap the button which is shown from the network request success callback
mainWindow.buttons()["dialog.button.okay"].tap();

// End the wait scope
target.popTimeout();
```